# Don't changed data on jsp after update data in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsp, servlets, jpa, eclipselink

I have class to get data from db and servlet for send this data to jsp. If i insert or delete row in the table (using pgAdmin), data on jsp is updated (with new data), but if i update existing date in table, it's not updated on the jsp (only after restart glassfish). 
Class using for ORM:

```
package db_classes;
@Entity
public class heading {
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Long themeCount;
private Collection<topic> topicsById;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "theme_count")
public Long getThemeCount() {
    return themeCount;
}

public void setThemeCount(Long themeCount) {
    this.themeCount = themeCount;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "headingByIdHeading")
public Collection<topic> getTopicsById() {
    return topicsById;
}

public void setTopicsById(Collection<topic> topicsById) {
    this.topicsById = topicsById;
}
}
```

servlet:

```
    package controllers;

/**
 * Created by Otani on 25.02.2015.
 */
@WebServlet(name = "Heading_parser")
@Stateful
public class Heading_parser extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Heading_processes heading_processes = new Heading_processes();
        getServletContext().setAttribute("headings",heading_processes.getAllHeading());
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

    }
    }
```

Method of Heading_processes for get data:

```
public List<heading> getAllHeading() {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT h FROM heading h");
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And fragment of index.jsp:

```
<table class="table-border">
    <tbody>

    <c:forEach var = "heading" items = "${headings}">
        <tr>
            <td class="msg-img"><img src="image/message.png" width="32" height="32" alt="theme"></td>
            <td><a href="showtopic.jsp?topic?id=${heading.id}" title=${heading.name}>${heading.name}</a></td>
            <td class="count">${heading.themeCount} Тем <br> Сообщений:</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

UPD:
Add pesistance.xml:

```
 <persistence-unit name="forum">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>db_classes.heading</class>
        <class>db_classes.message</class>
        <class>db_classes.topic</class>
        <class>db_classes.uncensoredWords</class>
        <class>db_classes.users</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/forum"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="****"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you have JPA caching enabled. You will need to post the JPA configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a caching issue.

See the following documentation:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

> By default EclipseLink uses a shared object cache, that caches a
>   subset of all objects read and persisted for the persistence unit. The
>   EclipseLink shared cache differs from the local EntityManager cache.
>   **The shared cache exists for the duration of the persistence unit
>   (EntityManagerFactory, or server) and is shared by all EntityManagers
>   and users of the persistence unit**. The local EntityManager cache is
>   not shared, and only exists for the duration of the EntityManager or
>   transaction.
>
> The benefit of the shared cache, is that once an object has been read,
>   if it is read again using the find operation, the database does not
>   need to be accessed. Also if the object is read through any Query, it
>   will not need to be rebuilt, and its relationships will not need to be
>   re-fetched.
>
> **The limitation of the shared cache, is that if the database is changed
>   directly through JDBC, or by another application or server, the
>   objects in the shared cache will be stale.**

You can quickly verify this by adding the following to your JPA config and seeing if the problem goes away:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Whether or not you want to disable the cache permanently depends on your use case i.e. will other applications be updating these entities in the real world.

Comment: @Okadzaki - you should accept as the correct answer.