# JPA refresh collection

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a collection defined in my entity as follows:

```
@Entity
public class User {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

Lets say I insert a Role by hand into the database.

When I then call `user.getRoles()` JPA does not recognize the new object. What do I have to do in order to say JPA to load the values again from the database? (I use EclipseLink)

Comment: The recommended approach is to manage both sides of the relationship, just like in any ordinary POJO.

Comment: Also, if you use EclipseLink, why did you tag Hibernate?

Comment: what do you mean? do you mind providing a small example?

Comment: Probably caching. See explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28727485/1356423

Comment: "*Managing both sides of the relationship*" means making the corresponding changes to the collection on the inverse side of the relationship, when an entity is added, deleted or modified. The JPA provider is not responsible for doing this by specification. The behaviour is provider specific, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using L2 cache, and your entity is already cached at the time you add the row directly in the database.

With JPA, try [`em.refresh(entity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)). This will fetch all persistent fields from the database. Or, turn off L2 caching, if underlying database will be modified outside of your application on regular basis.

Comment: This is completely correct. if you run a manual sql query jpa is not aware of it bcause of the l2 cache and you should explicetly refresh it